# JQuery Accessing Variables in a Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, default

How can I access and set variables in a plugin from document ready. I have found some related questions here on Stack Overflow but they didn't help me understand how this can be done.

```
(function($){
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
      var myVar1 = true;
      var myVar2 = true;
      var myVar3 = true;

      ....
      
      if(myVar1 == true){
         // do something
         ...
      }

      ....
   }
})(jQuery);

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $.fn.myPlugin.myVar1 = false;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think the much better question is why you feel that this is a good idea? Poking into a plugin this way is unlikely to have desirable effects, there are generally options and callbacks to do whatever it is you have in mind. What is the context here?

Comment: @Sinetheta I believe he meant his own plugin

Comment: @Sinetheta To do the defaults and option as per jquery manual, I'd have to rewrite all my code and I wouldn't know where to begin. I am a complete newbie. I thought accessing a variable and changing its value would be a very simple thing. Almost all of the answers assume that I know what I am doing -- if that was the case, I wouldn't be here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `var`:

```
this.myVar1 = true;
this.myVar2 = true;

....
```

Comment: How would I reference this in my if statement? Just call the property or this.propertyName? I tried both ways but its not working. Thank you

Comment: @user1002039 you should be able to do this: `if(this.myVar1) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate/

There are some examples on how to use public properties and methods in a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to call it outside the plugin?
Put your variable as Boolean option, than if true or false you build a different function...
When you will use the plugin in a separate file you will write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#id').myPlugin() {
         //options
      }
   });
```

in this way if in your option your variable will be set to true or false it will execute two different functions...

Btw if you need to call a variable outside the plugin this is the way:

```
$('#id').data('myPlugin').option.foo;
```

Comment: This is indeed one of the recommended ways as per the jquery documentation on functions.

Comment: Those variables are set as the defaults. I want to be able to turn the related functions on or off when I use the plugin.

Comment: @user1002039 take a look at my edit. Store your variable into options or setting, where you want (plugin.settings = { //your vars }) and than you can call it.